# How to specify which unique value to use

Tags: excel, vba

Continuation of my VBA project. the last piece I need is to ignore duplicate Segment IDs and only list each unique Segment ID once. Below is the current bugged code CGPT gave me for unique listing

```
Sub FilterAndOutputV7_2S()
    Dim wsPJK As Worksheet
    Dim wsCommonParts As Worksheet
    Dim rngCommonParts As Range
    Dim outputCell As Range
    Dim commonPart As Range
    Dim filteredData As Range
    Dim itemNumber As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim uniqueValues As Object ' Use Dictionary object
    Dim cellValue As Variant
    Dim outputRange As Range
    
    ' Set your worksheet references
    Set wsPJK = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PJK")
    Set wsCommonParts = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Common Parts")
    
    ' Set the range in Common Parts sheet where you want to loop through item numbers
    Set rngCommonParts = wsCommonParts.Range("A2:A" & wsCommonParts.Cells(wsCommonParts.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    ' Initialize output starting cell
    Set outputCell = wsCommonParts.Range("B2")
    
    ' Loop through each cell in the Common Parts sheet's range
    For Each commonPart In rngCommonParts
        ' Get the item number from Common Parts sheet
        itemNumber = commonPart.Value
        
        ' Find the last row in column B of PJK sheet
        lastRow = wsPJK.Cells(wsPJK.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        
        ' Filter data in PJK sheet based on the current item number
        wsPJK.Range("A:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=itemNumber
        
        ' Check if there are visible cells in column B (excluding header)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set filteredData = wsPJK.Range("B2:B" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        ' Initialize Dictionary object to store unique values
        Set uniqueValues = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
        ' Output the filtered data to the Common Parts sheet (left-aligned) without duplicates
        outputCell.Value = itemNumber
        Set outputRange = outputCell.Offset(0, 1)
        
        If Not filteredData Is Nothing Then
            For Each cellValue In filteredData
                On Error Resume Next
                uniqueValues.Add cellValue.Value, CStr(cellValue.Value)
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next cellValue
            
            ' Output unique values to the next columns and left-align
            outputRange.Resize(uniqueValues.Count, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(uniqueValues.Keys)
            outputRange.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        End If
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        ' Clear the filter in PJK sheet
        wsPJK.AutoFilterMode = False
        
        ' Move the output cell to the next row with a cell break
        Set outputCell = outputCell.Offset(IIf(filteredData Is Nothing, 1, uniqueValues.Count + 2), 0)
    Next commonPart
End Sub
```

in 'PJK'! Item X (A:A) may be listed 3 times in Segment _0X (B:B) but I only need to see Segment _03 matched and listed once in the output, not 3 times

Comment: "current bugged code" - how exactly is it "bugged" ?

Comment: `Collection` doesn't have an `Items` property.  Maybe use a Dictionary instead?

Comment: Ah sorry, Error 13 Type Mismatch immediately

Comment: *On which line* ?

Comment: I am solely relying on CGPT for this and here for help. This type of thing is way outside my job description but I am known for getting the job done. A fluent coder I am not however

Comment: Debug highlighted 'For Each cellValue In filteredData.Value' in the error

Comment: Get rid of the `.Value`.

Comment: now I get Error 438 at line 'outputCell.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, uniqueValues.Count) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(uniqueValues.Items)'

Comment: See second comment above.

Comment: That worked. Thank very much once again. I have updated the code in my OP to the working version for others to reference